# Format a pc with a GRUB error

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, chromium, format

i have a pc with a grub error {caused by deleting ubuntu partition in XP dual boot}
i would like to format the hard disk and install a new OS [chromium]

i do not have either the ubuntu or the XP installation drives
although i do have the chromium bootable drive

when i try to boot from the chrome bootable USB its says "your system is repairing itself" and restarts. this keeps happening over and over again.

i just want to format my HDD completely and start over with chromium (i have no important data on the HDD)

Answer (score 0):

Go and download a live boot-able ISO of "Gparted" and delete all of your partitions on your hard drive, then try to run the installer for Chromium.